# UNIX script abruptly ending due to ssh command

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ssh invocation in script function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932774/ssh-invocation-in-script-function)

Below UNIX script abruptly ends while reading second line from file. When I comment 'ssh' command the script works as expected. I think I will have to run ssh command in a different process, but haven't got a handle yet as regards to how to do that. Any help in resolving this problem is highly appreciated.

```
*#!/usr/bin/ksh
exec 3<&0
exec 0<./bulkInput.dat
#cat ./bulkInput.dat | while read searchToken || (echo "reading failedi $?" &&  false)
index=0
while true
do
        index=`expr $index + 1`
        if [ $index -gt 450 ]
        then
                echo "Index limit reached. Now exiting"
                exit 0
        fi
        read searchToken
        if [ $? -ne "0" ]
        then
                echo "Read failed"
        fi
        echo "Search token is "${searchToken}
        echo "************************************ **********************************"
        echo "plsa0666 WSIP server " > WSIP.log
        ssh zq742888@plsa0666 'grep -r '$searchToken' /logs/jas/was60/wsip/wsip*/wsip*' >> WSIP.log
        echo "plsa0667 WSIP server " >> WSIP.log
        #ssh zq742888@plsa0667 'grep -r '$searchToken' /logs/jas/was60/wsip/wsip*/wsip*' >> WSIP.log
        echo "plsa0668 WSIP server " >> WSIP.log
        #ssh zq742888@plsa0668 'grep -r '$searchToken' /logs/jas/was60/wsip/wsip*/wsip*' >> WSIP.log
        echo "plsa4407 WSIP server " >> WSIP.log
        #ssh zq742888@plsa4407 'grep -r '$searchToken' /logs/jas/was60/wsip/wsip*/wsip*' >> WSIP.log
        echo "plsa0412 server " >> WSIP.log
        cp WSIP.log bulk/WSIP.log_${searchToken}
        echo $?
done
exec 0<&3
echo "Exiting script"*
```

Answer (score 1):

`ssh(1)` is reading all of stdin and exhausting it, causing the next shell `read` to return false and break the loop.  Try one of these:

```
ssh -n zq742888@plsa0666 ...
```

or

```
ssh < /dev/null zq742888@plsa0666 ...
```

to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Pilcrow!! That worked! SO rocks!! And to think of it I spent 4-5 hours figuring this out!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Run the ssh command from the shell prompt and see what it does. If it is asking for input (e.g. password) then that may be problem.

There is also a flag to run in script mode(from memory -b but you should check) and that may also help you.

The -i flag allows you to specify the key to use if that is the problem.